# Find and replace consecutive string values in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Suppose I have a list that holds a list of column names:

```
columns = [
        'Village Trustee V Belleville', 'Unnamed: 74', 'Unnamed: 75',
        'Village President V Black Earth', 'Village Trustee V Black Earth',
        'Unnamed: 78', 'Unnamed: 79', 'Village President V Blue Mounds',
        'Village Trustee V Blue Mounds', 'Unnamed: 82',
        'Village Trustee V Cottage Grove', 'Unnamed: 94', 'Unnamed: 95',
        'Village President V Cross Plains', 'Village Trustee V Cross Plains',
        'Unnamed: 98', 'Unnamed: 99'
        ]
```

And I want to find all `Unnamed: XX` values and replace them consecutively with the first valid string. For example:

Input:
`'Village Trustee V Belleville', 'Unnamed: 74', 'Unnamed: 75'`

Output:
`'Village Trustee V Belleville', 'Village Trustee V Belleville', 'Village Trustee V Belleville'`

For this I have a function:

```
def rename_unnamed(columns):
    current_value = None
    pattern = re.compile(r'^Unnamed:\s\d+$')
    for column_index, column in enumerate(columns):
        if re.match(pattern, column):
            columns[column_index] = current_value
        else:
            current_value = column
    return columns
```

Which does the job pretty fine, however, I was wondering if this could be improved and/or simplified, as this looks like a mouthful for rather a simple task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Don't mutate input and return.

  If I need to pass `columns` unedited to two different functions, than your function will seem like it's not mutating `columns` and I wouldn't have to perform a copy of the data. But this isn't the case.
- You may want to potentially error if there are no values before the first "Unnamed" value.
- You may want to make `pattern` an argument, to allow reusability of the function. And instead use change it to a callback to allow even more reusability.

Overall your function's pretty good. I don't think it can be made much shorter.

```
def value_or_previous(iterator, undefined, default=None):
    prev_item = default
    for item in iterator:
        if not undefined(item):
            prev_item = item
        yield prev_item


def rename_unnamed(columns):
    return list(value_or_previous(columns, re.compile(r'^Unnamed:\s\d+$').match))
```

Answer (score 4):

In case you need to modify the initial `columns` list (mutable data structure) you don't need to `return` it.

The crucial pattern can be moved out to the *top* making it reusable and accessible for other potential routines or *inline* conditions:

```
UNNAMED_PAT = re.compile(r'^Unnamed:\s\d+$')
```

As the function's responsibility is to ***back fill*** (backward filling) items matched by specific regex pattern I'd rename it appropriately like say **`backfill_by_pattern`**. The *search* pattern is passed as an argument.

I'll suggest even more concise solution based on replacement of *search* items by the item at the *previous* index:

```
def backfill_by_pattern(columns, pat):
    fill_value = None
    for i, column in enumerate(columns):
        if pat.match(column):
            columns[i] = columns[i - 1] if i else fill_value
```

Sample usage:

```
backfill_by_pattern(columns, pat=UNNAMED_PAT)
print(columns)
```

The output:

```
['Village Trustee V Belleville',
 'Village Trustee V Belleville',
 'Village Trustee V Belleville',
 'Village President V Black Earth',
 'Village Trustee V Black Earth',
 'Village Trustee V Black Earth',
 'Village Trustee V Black Earth',
 'Village President V Blue Mounds',
 'Village Trustee V Blue Mounds',
 'Village Trustee V Blue Mounds',
 'Village Trustee V Cottage Grove',
 'Village Trustee V Cottage Grove',
 'Village Trustee V Cottage Grove',
 'Village President V Cross Plains',
 'Village Trustee V Cross Plains',
 'Village Trustee V Cross Plains',
 'Village Trustee V Cross Plains']
```

Comment: I get `None` when running this script; am I running it correctly?

Comment: @alexyorke, the very 1st sentence about *(mutable data structure)* should have given you a hint